# How to find the number of "prime digit primes" under 'n'?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

The sequence of "prime numbers whose digits are prime": `2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 37, 53, 73, 223, ...`

Reference to this sequence: [A019546: Primes whose digits are prime](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C23%2C&language=english&go=Search)

Given an integer $n$, how can I find out the number of numbers appearing in this sequence under $n$? (or, is it possible?)

Comment: Brute force seems like a useful approach here.  Considering we don't even have a way that doesn't rely on brute force somehow to count the number of *primes* less than $n$, I would expect counting the number of these special primes to be just as much of a challenge.

Comment: Brute force accomplishes this in time $O(n^{0.60206})$.  That's actually significantly worse than the best algorithms for computing $\pi(n)$, but I can't imagine a way to do better than brute force by more than a power of $\log n$, say.